# My PHP Contact form is not working

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I'm having a problem with my contact form and I don't know if it is the contact form that is a problem or the PHP, can anyone look at it and tell me what's wrong?Like I said, I have looked it over and over to make it to see what the problem

```
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="group">
                <input id="name" type="text"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
                <label>Name</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="group">
                <input id="email" type="email"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
                <label>Email</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="messege"></textarea>
        <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Your Messege</label>
    </div>
    <button class="ripple">Send</button>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP Part;

```
<?php
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Return-Path: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Priority: 1' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  //  Replace with your email
  mail( "email@example.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], $headers );

}
?>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: A: `<form>` => `<form method="get">` that's what it defaults to; use "post". You also have no name attributes.

Comment: What I mean by not working is that it will not send. When you click the button the website, it does not go anywhere.

Comment: ask Marc; he gave you an answer; he just left out one thing I said up here.

Comment: plus, if you're using 2 different files, then again... `<form>` with no action equals sending to the same file and defaults to what I already said; Marc, did not (c'mon on Marc, help the girl out ;-) ). Plus, if javascript is being used, then you need to post that.

Comment: `<button class="ripple">Send</button>` if you're not using javascript with this, then that button does nothing really. You need a submit type. We also don't know if you're using this on a local machine or hosted site. If local, then "how"?

Comment: use input type="submit" instead of button and give proper name to all your attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You have no `name` attributes on your form fields:

```
<input id="name" type="text"><span class="hi [..snip..]
```

`id` is **NOT** used for form submissions. No names, no fields submitted.

Even some BASIC debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` would have shown you the problem.

Comment: Okay I'm going to a little dumb and disclose that is a bootstrap theme that I bought, Since I'm not learning to code, I wanted to test my skills and try to edit a theme when I bought the theme, the documentation stated all I had to was change my email in the sendmail.php file, which I did. but when you press send it does nothing. So what do I need to change exactly?

Comment: if that's literally the code you bought, then you should probably ask for your money back...

Comment: Good thing I wasn't taking a sip of my coffee for that one ^

Comment: You could've gotten any PHP Contact Form code off the internet for free. Ask your money back and accept his answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have added 'id' in form, but you can not access the input value by the use of id, instead you have to use 'name' attribute. You also have to give action and method attribute in the form tag. so that the input values will be send to the selected path or file by the method you have choosen. I have updated your code with solution. You should try this.

```
<form method="post" action="filename or path">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="group">
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
                <label>Name</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="group">
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email"><span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
                <label>Email</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="message" id="messege"></textarea>
        <span class="highlight"></span><span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Your Messege</label>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="button" class="ripple" value="send">
</form>
```

**But if you have written your php code in the same file, than you do not need to add method and action attribute in the `<form>`. and you should add the name attribute in the `<button>`, so that you can assure that the php code will be executed if the button is clicked.**

```
<button name="submit" class="ripple">Send</button>
```

and update your php code with this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// Email Submit
// Note: filter_var() requires PHP >= 5.2.0
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {

  // detect & prevent header injections
  $test = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|to:)/i";
  foreach ( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
    if ( preg_match( $test, $val ) ) {
      exit;
    }
  }

$headers = 'From: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Return-Path: ' . $_POST["name"] . '<' . $_POST["email"] . '>' . "\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Priority: 1' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  //  Replace with your email
  mail( "email@example.com", $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], $headers );  
}
else
{
   //echo error
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Dhara, Thank you for the solution! but it still remains not to be working.

Comment: can you please update your code with your new code? and have you written your HTML and PHP code in different file or same file?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" class="ripple" value="Send">, try this instead of button.